# PostgreSQL using to_char for later batter aggregation, how to convert the Month part back to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, date, casting

I am using the following to transfrom the date variable to YYYY and Mon

```
select
to_char(date, 'Mon')                     as month,
extract(year from date)                  as year,
v1,
count(v2) as count
from data
group by 1,2,3
order by 2,1;
```

However, when I do an order by, it does not order my data properly. So I think I have to convert Mon either to a number or back to a date to be able to sort it properly. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Of course not.  It is ordering by the month name.

Instead, just order by the date:

```
order by date
```

If this were an aggregation query, then you would use an aggregation function:

```
order by min(date)
```

Comment: The reason why I break down the date variable into month and year, is because I want to group by month and year. But again...how I can transform the variable in a way, so I can also sort by month...not only year..

Comment: @kris030 . . . I actually answered that question.  `ORDER BY` the minimum (or maximum) of the date.  This question usually arises with aggregation queries, which is why I included that.

Comment: Don't break your date into month and year columns. Just truncate your date to contain just year and month [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html) function. Here that would be date_trunc('month', month_date). Technically it the 1st of the month. But result is what you need and the result is still a valid date; so all built in date processing still valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a derived table where the grouping is done on a proper date value and convert it only for display purposes:

```
select to_char(month_date, 'Mon' as month,
       extract(year from month_date) as year,
       v1,
       count
from (       
  select date_trunc('month', "date") as month_date
         v1,
         count(v2) as count
  from data
  group by 1,2
)
order by month_date
```